# Wrap some field in div in angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

How can I wrap some field in div and don't use fieldGroup.I want to all div have class 'left-layout' will wrapped by class 'left-container'
Controller:

```
vm.fields = [
      {
        key: 'first',
        type: 'input',
        className: 'left-layout',
        model: vm.model.name,
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'First Name'
        }
      },
      {
        key: 'last',
        type: 'input',
        model: vm.model.name,
        className: 'left-layout',
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'Last Name'
        }
      },
      {
        key: 'email',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'Email Address',
          type: 'email'
        }
      }
];
```

index.html

```
<script>
      $('.left-layout').wrapAll("<div class='left-container'></div>");
</script>
```

This is jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/honuxi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you want to use fieldGroup?  That's how you do that.  You add the className to the fieldGroup and then wrap the fieldGroup with a wrapper you have pre-defined in the formly config:

```
   .config(function config(formlyConfigProvider) {
                formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
                    name: 'left-container',
                    template: '<div class="left-container">  
                                 <formly-transclude></formly-transclude>  
                              </div>'                                                                                                      
                });
    }


vm.fields = [
   {
     wrapper: 'left-container',
     className: 'left-layout',
     fieldGroup: [
      {
        key: 'first',
        type: 'input',
        model: vm.model.name,
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'First Name'
        }
      },
      {
        key: 'last',
        type: 'input',
        model: vm.model.name,
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'Last Name'
        }
      },
      {
        key: 'email',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'Email Address',
          type: 'email'
        }
      }
   }]
];
```